# Where can I find the CSS-only Modal example on MDN?

Tags: css

I've been looking for the example code on `Mozilla Developer Network` (MDN).

I had once stumbled upon it and much to my surprise I didn't know it was possible to have CSS-only modals without javascript.

I can't seem to find the example now and I would like to have the link to it.

I could find other examples but I'd rather look at the code from a reputable source such as MDN.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic is made by the `:target` pseudo selector. Here is the link from MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target

And the example: https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/4607/lightbox.html#

Also you can take a look here:
http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/

And I found another good example in code pen:
http://codepen.io/maccadb7/pen/nbHEg

```
.modal:before {
  content: "";
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
.modal:target:before {
  display: block;
}
.modal:target .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  top: 20%;
}
.modal-dialog {
  background: #fefefe;
  border: #333333 solid 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: -100%;
  z-index: 11;
  width: 360px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -500%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -500%);
  transform: translate(0, -500%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's what it was! I was so close. I was looking up `:focus`